# Cannot access a RUBY file via browser but can access it from command line

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra

I created a file with name `server.rb`

```
require 'bundler' ; Bundler.require
get '/hello-world' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

when i access it as  `curl http://localhost:4567` from command line I can easily see `Hello World!` but when I access via browser as `http://172.16.16.14:4567`

`172.16.16.14` is the ip of the local server and when I hit `http://172.16.16.14/` I can see the default page of nginx.

I get

```
This site can’t be reached
172.16.16.14 refused to connect.
```

Comment: Ruby server is bound to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @miknik I installed nginx and ruby on a centos machine, proceeded to gem sinatra, generally i install apache for php application and I am aware of httpd.conf, do I need to set anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @miknik it's quite possible that it has to do with the servers `bind` option.

Documented on Sintara website: http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address

This will allow connections from any host:

```
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
```

[Here's the actual PR](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/634) for making the default bind address `localhost` rather than `0.0.0.0` which will allow connections from any host. https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/634